# how to getText() from disabled div in selenium with no value attribute

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to read the example String "20" from the hidden div.
but this div does not contain any value attribute.

```
<div class="input-cell-accessType-disabled active" style="border: none;"></div>
```

I have tried the following to gettext out of it

```
String theTextIWant = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].value;",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='input-cell field-615']//following-sibling::div[@class='input-cell-accessType-disabled active']")));

System.out.println("textineed"+theTextIWant); 

String theTextIWant1 =(String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='input-cell field-615']//following-sibling::div[@class='input-cell-accessType-disabled active']")));
System.out.println("textineed"+theTextIWant1);
```

Attached Screenshot of the html content from which i am trying to get text.[image: Please View Image Here]

Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any String with text as **20** in the shared _HTML_. Additionally please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Yes, There is no String as 20 in that code but the think is it is coming as bind may be when we execute these in console we get it as 20 angular.element($0).scope().itemData.Position.ProductPackage.CasePack

Comment: Wait for the binding (JS/AJAX) to get completed and reflect in the _HTML DOM_ then you can retrieve it.

Comment: Yes did that thanks for the help..

Comment: @ChaitanyaPujari Can you add the code how you fixed it so others can learn from it?

Comment: As @Frank mentioned you can self Answer your Question and Accept it as well for the benefit of the future readers.